# add class using jquery based on class name and an id

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form that is validated using validationform.io. There is no out of the box support for Bootstrap select, select fields.

I have this bit of jQuery code that will add the `has-success` class that adds a green border around the select box and this works fine. But as I'm only finding the `.btn-light` class it changes anything using that class.

Is there a way to add a CSS selector where class=".btn-light" and data-id="roleId"?

This is my jQuery:

```
fv.on('core.field.valid', function(field) {   
    if (field === 'roleId') {     
        $('.btn-light').addClass("has-success"); 
    }      
});
```

This is the html for the select :

```html
<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-style="btn-light" name="roleId" id="roleId">
```

this is what the bootstrap-select converts it to when checking in developer tools :

```html
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="roleId" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the class and data in the selector field:

```
$('.btn-light[data-id="roleId"]').addClass("has-success");
```